# Why is the 'r' before strings in python so important?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am fairly new to the Django framework and for a couple of hours I was getting `TemplateNotFound` error returned when I tried to map my `views.py` to my `templates` directory. This issue was eventually solved just by inputting 'r' before my path to templates in `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')` to become `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, r'templates')`. I really want to understand better what function it carries out on the string. what is the big idea?

Comment: No, `r'templates'` is functionally identical to `'templates'`. Either the string was something different or your problem must have been something else.

Comment: Does [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) help?